# Initialising a reference in a const object

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

I have the following code:

```
class c_int {
public:
  int &i;
  c_int(int &in) : i(in) {
  };
  c_int(const int &in) : i(in) {
  };
};


int main (void) {

  const int i = 10;
  const c_int c(i); 

  std::cout << c.i << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it gives the following error message:

```
tmp.cpp:12:30: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from ex
presion of type 'const int'
```

I am having a bit of trouble, figuring out how to get this to work, how should I initialize a reference inside a const object?

Edit: Ideally I would like this object to serve for non-const ints too; when the object is not declared const.

Further Edit:

I wish to use the object like this also:

```
int main (void) {

  int i = 10;
  c_int c(i); // for some reason this calls the 2nd of my constructors, does name mangling not take const into account?
  c.i = 9;    

  std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that `c_int::i` is a `int &` and you are trying to bind it to a `const int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you have two different classes. One which holds a const reference, and one which holds a non-const reference. This is similar to the way standard containers have both `iterator` and `const_iterator` as two seperate classes.

```
class c_int {
public:
  int &i;
  c_int(int &in) : i(in) {};
};

class const_c_int {
public:
  int const &i;
  c_int(int const &in) : i(in) {};
};
```

If you want to avoid repeating code, you could make a template:

```
template<typename T>
class c_generic {
public:
  T& i;
  c_generic(T& in) :i(in) {}
};

typedef c_generic<int> c_int;
typedef c_generic<int const> const_c_int;
```

Comment: thanks, that is one solution, it doesn't seem very DRY though?

Comment: @jayjay: I've provided an alternative.

Comment: @jayjay This is one of `const`'s downsides in a few places- it leads to unwanted code duplication in some scenarios. Yes, you can work around it usually, as here.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not that your object is `const` : it is that you are trying to bind a const reference to a non-const one : this is illegal.

You can bind a const reference to a const member :

```
class c_int {
public:
  const int &j;
  c_int(const int &in) : j(in){  };
};


int main (void) {

  const int i = 10;
  c_int c(i); 

  std::cout << c.j << std::endl;
}
```

You can still uses two different classes for `const` and `non const` objects, or if you **really** need a single class and know what you are doing, use a `const_cast` (really discouraged : any attempt to modify the object will be undefined behavior) :

```
class c_int {
public:
  int& i;
  c_int(int& in) : i(in){ }
  c_int(const int& in) : i(const_cast<int&>(in)){ } // Very wrong
};
```

Or, forget about passing by reference and use value semantics :

```
class c_int {
public:
  int i;
  c_int(int in) : i(in){ }
};
```

---

**Edit:**

You can still add a constructor taking a non-const reference for cases where your int argument is not const :

```
class c_int {
public:
  const int &j;
  c_int(const int &in) : j(in){  };
  c_int(int &in) : j(in){ }
};


int main (void) {

  const int i = 10;
  const c_int c(i); 
  std::cout << c.j << '\n';

  int i2 = 11;
  const c_int d(i2); 
  std::cout << d.j << '\n';  
}
```

[**Live demo.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a6758a47d2520f1)

Comment: thanks, what if I need to also have copies of the object where the int reference is not const

Comment: ah, thanks again should have been clearer though sorry, I meant a non-const property, I would like to modify the int using the object i.e. `c.i = 5`; (when the object is not declared const).

Comment: @jayjay : you are asking to modify a `const` object through a non-const reference : this is illegal and has **undefined behavior** (you can do it with `const_cast<>`, but it's UB). Either you take const ref and you never modify the object, or you take non-const ones. In your case, I would simply take the object by value (not by reference) and everything would be fine : `c_int(int in)`

Comment: I don't think I am explaining myself very well, sorry, either that or I am being an idiot (or possibly both)... I will add to my question above, hang on

Comment: @quantdev "you are asking to modify a const object through a non-const reference". He does not. He wants `const c_int` to hold a reference to `const int` and not be able to modify it and non const `c_int` to hold reference to int and be able to modify it

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the meaning of `const`. A reference is always constant (regardless whether it is accessed from a `const` object or not): you cannot change the reference and as class member it must be initialised in the constructor's initialiser list.

The situation is equivalent to that with pointers. Consider:

```
const int*a;              // pointer to a const int: cannot change *a, but can change a
int*const b;              // pointer to an int, cannot change b, but can change *b
const int*const c;        // constant pointer to a constant int: cannot change c nor *c

int&x;                    // equivalent to pointer b
const int&y;              // equivalent to pointer c
```

A reference is always constant, hence the second `const` with pointers is always on.

Answer (score 1):

You want the same class `c_int` to work as const reference and non const reference to `int` depend on "constness" of c_int itself. Unfortunately it is not possible in C++. For the same reason `iterator` and `const_iterator` are different types in STL for example. You can use the same method though:

```
class c_int {
public:
  int &j;
  c_int( int &in) : j(in){  }
};

class const_c_int {
public:
  const int &j;
  const_c_int( const int &in) : j(in){  }
  const_c_int( const c_int &in) : j(in.j){  }
};
```

So you will be able to convert `c_int` to `const_c_int`, but not vice versa

Comment: thanks, that's what I was afraid of, just to be clear I was hoping the "constness" of the property would be dependent on the "constness" of the object, not only the int itself. But Im guessing this still isn't possible?

Comment: @jayjay you missed Walter answer. Reference is a bad example. Imagine your class has a pointer instead. Then consteness of your class would mean that you cannot change that pointer, ie point it to another `int`, not that data, it points to, cannot be changed. With reference constness of your object does not really matter, as you cannot change reference, but principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

A reference member has to either be `const` or not. And it's not possible to have a different constructor for `const` objects than non-`const` objects.

One option is to actually have two different classes, one for wrapping ints and one for wrapping const ints. Similar to how `iterator` and `const_iterator` are different types. This could either be via a template parameter, or the non-const version could derive from the const version, or they could be completely standalone.

To use a single non-template class you're going to need to use a function that returns the reference, so that it can be overloaded on whether your object is `const` or not. Further, it'll have to be a property that is checked at runtime because it's always possible to cast a non-const object to const. For example:

```
class c_int
{
private:
    int const *p_int;
    bool is_const;

public:
    c_int(int &x): p_int(&x), is_const(false) {}
    c_int(int const &x): p_int(&x), is_const(true) {}

    int &i() 
    { 
         if ( is_const ) 
              throw std::runtime_error("non-const access for const int");
         return const_cast<int &>(*p_int);
    }

    int const &i() const { return *p_int; }
};
```

It would be possible to have a default constructor that does nothing and then you use a function to set mutable class members , but then you lose the benefits of the constructor.